# C# Toolstrip Causes Supporting Form to Grow

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I've rewritten a toolbar that sits at the top of the user's screen. It works, but for some reason, though the app consists of just a form with a Fill-Docked ToolStrip, I cannot get it to stay at the size I specify. It's supposed to be the size of the Windows titlebar, as designed in Visual Studio, but as soon as I run it, it's grown in height by five or six pixels. Everything is set rigidly, the Form and ToolStrip are set to AutoSize=FALSE and I've specified the size in pixels the form should be. I cannot work out what is resizing the form at runtime; the ToolStrip is Docked on Fill mode so it should not cause the form to grow. It all looks perfect in the GUI builder, and I copied most of the configuration from the old VB.Net toolbar it will replace. Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when the ToolStrip is not docked to fill?

Comment: @jberger If it's not docked, then the form shows empty space beneath the toolbar. I used a quick fix by making the background transparent, but it still means the form is expanding

Comment: You said you rewrote it; have you checking in the code to make sure you are not setting any properties on the toolstrip that wind up overriding the settings you apply in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found an answer but I'll make sure this is closed. I turned the form transparent and it accomplished what I needed. Still unsure why the form expanded when run.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but have you tried changing the **AutoScaleMode** property of the **Form** to something other than **Font**?